# SpringBatchTest multiple test classes - throws InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I am using `@SpringBatchTest` to run e2e tests on my Spring Batch application.
Everything works well except when I run both of my test classes (divided my tests into positive/negative test classes) together. The first one runs and tests pass, but the second fails trying to launch the context again. Since it is already launched, the tests fail on `InstanceAlreadyExistsException`.

Both my test classes are defined with the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestConfiguration.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({MockitoTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

**EDIT:**

In general, what my test does is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {HardDeleteTestConfiguration.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({MockitoTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class TestClass1 {
@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
@Autowired
private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

@Before
public void setUp() {
     jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
}

@Test
public void SpringBatchTest() {
    // preparing data for test
    // ...

    JobExecution jobExecution = 
    jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(createJobParams("myKey","myValue"));

   // Perform assertions
   // ...
}
}

private void createJobParams(String key, value) {
    JobParameters uniqueJobParameters = jobLauncherTestUtils.getUniqueJobParameters();
    JobParametersBuilder paramsBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder(uniqueJobParameters);
    paramsBuilder.addString(key, value);
    return paramsBuilder.toJobParameters();
}
}
```

`TestClass2` is the same as `TestClass1` with only different data preparation and assertions.

Also my test properties are as follows:

```
# Spring Boot configuration
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
# Spring Batch configuration
spring.batch.job.names=myBatchJob
```

I have tried all combinations of `true` and `false` for the previous flags but it does not make any difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "run both of my test classes [...] together"? Please share the minimal code of your test to be able to help you.

Comment: I mean right click on 'Java' test resources where both test classes are in, and choose "Run 'All Tests'...". Unfortunately I cannot provide the code of the test due to company policy. But the cause is that when running the 2nd test class the test framework is trying to load the Spring context again after the first already loaded it, resulting in the exception. The question is how to prevent additional context loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually we realized it was an in-house framework wrapping Spring that caused the problem (stupid static instantiations on context loading and such).

To solve we used `@MockBean` on one problematic class, and `@EnableAutoConfiguration( exclude = ProblematicConfiguration.class)` in the annotation located above the test class.

Answer (score 0):

> Since it is already launched, the tests fail on InstanceAlreadyExistsException.

This means the datasource is reused between tests, and when the second test runs, it will try to launch the same job instance.

In your `createJobParameters()` method, you can use [`JobLauncherTestUtils#getUniqueJobParameters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/JobLauncherTestUtils.html#getUniqueJobParameters--) to create unique job parameters and run a different job instance for each test.

Comment: I tried: it was a good shot but unfortunately did not help. Still getting `InstanceAlreadyExistsException`. Anything else you can think of that I might try?